# What is more efficient in terms of time and memory is it hash table where each element is a tree or tested hash table?

Tags: data-structures, tree, hashtable

[image: Array of trees vs array of arrays]

I am trying to solve some problems but I don't know what is the best and more efficient way in terms of run time and memory is to use the tested hash table or to use the hash table where each element is a tree

Comment: What do you mean by `tested hash table` and `the hash table where each element is a tree`?

Comment: In hash table specifically what is know as separate chaining every index in the table can have another data structure such as tree or another hash table this is what i mean.